# Why is Saudi Arabia reluctant to convene an FM-level meeting in OIC?

Tags: pakistan, saudi-arabia

- [Saudi reluctant to accept Pakistan's request for immediate OIC meeting on Kashmir](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/international/world-news/saudi-reluctant-to-accept-pakistans-request-for-immediate-oic-meeting-on-kashmir-report/articleshow/73985145.cms)

Pakistan and Saudi Arabia are at odds with each other as to the convening of an FM-level meeting regarding human rights violations in Indian Kashmir. Saudi Arabia has been blocking this meeting from the last year.

Why is Saudi Arabia reluctant to convene an FM-level meeting in OIC?

What is their issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Kashmir internal issue of India, says Saudi
>
> [tribuneindia.com/news/archive/nation/kashmir-internal-issue-of-india-says-saudi-854148](http://tribuneindia.com/news/archive/nation/kashmir-internal-issue-of-india-says-saudi-854148)

> “It has been our hope that the situation between India and Pakistan be de-escalated and resolved peacefully,” said Saudi Foreign Minister Adel Bin Ahmed Al-Jubeir.
>
> https://www.samaa.tv/global/2019/02/saudi-arabia-wants-the-kashmir-issue-to-be-resolved-peacefully-and-amicably/